# How to hide key filters (Metadata navigation) for a specific view

Tags: view, key-filter, metadata-navigation

I am working with metadata navigation and I want to use key filters only for one view out three views for document library.

Is it possible I can hide it from other two views?

Comment: why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Because it is not working with group by. I have 3 views, two of them have group by and because of this key filters is not working properly so I thought of putting all documents view without group by. I have checked key filters works fine without group by.

Comment: what is not working in group by?

Comment: Key filters does not work properly if we use group by, search will show you correct value in the brackets something like xxx(3) but when you expand it, it  shows all the values those are not related to search.

Comment: I can group and the key filters work fine. Do you have any custom code on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Html source code and paste the following code:

```
<style>#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_ListViewKeyFilters_ctl00_FilterFormContainer {DISPLAY: none;}</style>
```